# How to set content for quill editor?

Tags: javascript, quill

I am trying to set content like this:

```
  quill.setContents("<div class='r'>some text</div> ");
```

But it does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 10):

assigning it to the innerHTML usually works. try this `quill.root.innerHTML = "<div class='r'>Some text</div>";`

Answer (score 9):

For me (Quill 1.3.6), `.pasteHTML` works:

```
quill.pasteHTML("<div class='r'>some text</div> ");
```

`.setText()` does not allow the setting of HTML and instead encodes HTML entities to show as plain text.

`.setContents()` didn't seem to work at all for me either.

`.root.innerHTML()` did not work either (threw a Javascript error).

Answer (score 0):

Using setText you can set HTML data

```
var quill = new Quill(".editor", {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  theme: "snow"
});

quill.setText("<div class='r'>some text</div>");
```

Read more from [quilljs document](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#settext)

Answer (score 0):

That's what have worked for me.

```
quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML = $('#'+el.id).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Content to quill-editor can be set using the ngModel :

```
<quill-editor [(ngModel)]="htmlContent"
        [modules]="quillConfig"
        (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)"
        ></quill-editor>
```

In .ts file:
Declare the variable as shown below and initialize value in constructor or ngOnInit().

```
htmlContent: string;
```